# iOS Make View fill screen

Tags: ios, xcode, view

I have a dumb question (I am new to iOS) I have a view and two subviews inside. But the subviews don't fill the view completely on iPhone 6, seems like they are sized for smaller iPhone. I keep googling but can't find a simple straight forward answer.

What do I need to do so my subviews fill entire screen in any iPhone?

Comment: find a tutorial on autolayouts, they are the key to solving these types of problems

Comment: What do u mean by fill?? Elaborate more

Comment: use hide status bar methods, add/remove navigationbar, you are done